# Index.php not opening after login

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

My login does not go to index.php after loging in, the page just refreshes
i am using MySqli and the database details are in the config file

This is the login.php

```
<form action="" method="post">
UserName:  <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="psw1"><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>

</form>
<?php 
require 'config1.php';

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $uname = $_POST["uname"];
    $psw1 = $_POST["psw1"];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '$uname'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        if($psw1 == $row["Password"]){
            $_SESSION["login"] = true;
            $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
        else{
            echo
            "<script> alert('wrong password'); </script>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo
        "<script> alert('User not regitered'); </script>";
    };

}
?>
```

This the index.php, hence the page i am supposed to go to after a successful login

```
`<?php
require 'config1.php';
if(!empty($_SESSION["id"])){
    $id = $_SESSION["id"];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = $id"); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
else{
    header("Location: login.php");
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h1>
<a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: I don’t know what your problem is, but I can tell you that sending error information over HTTP to HTML to pass on to JavaScript (via the echo and alert), along with header redirection, can make debugging very hard. At the early stages, just echo and die until you get the logic correct. Also, please don’t store the password in clear text like that.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I stored the password like that because Im still learning PHP and MySql and I want everything visible as I learn

Comment: Your site is vulnerable! [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Warning
Security warning: SQL injection

If the query contains any variable input then parameterized prepared statements should be used instead. Alternatively, the data must be properly formatted and all strings must be escaped using the mysqli_real_escape_string() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emitting html before you execute the header.  It does not work that way.  You cannot change the page after the browser has received some html, in this case the **form**.  So re-organise it this way.

```php
<?php 
require 'config1.php';

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $uname = $_POST["uname"];
    $psw1 = $_POST["psw1"];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '$uname'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        if($psw1 == $row["Password"]){
            $_SESSION["login"] = true;
            $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        }
        else{
            echo
            "<script> alert('wrong password'); </script>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo
        "<script> alert('User not regitered'); </script>";
    };

}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
UserName:  <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="psw1"><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Note that there is an **exit** after the header because you dont want the rest of the file getting executed.

### Note

This assumes that config1.php does not echo or emit any html